# Connect to AIX via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, aix

I have to connect the AIX machine through Linux via SSH command and i m not able to figure out how to connect. Can anybody help me with the command.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 3):

The commands are the same.
Check if SSHd is running (lssrc -s sshd) and not blocked by firewall (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixfiltering/index.html). Also check sshd config (especially port and interface listen to)

Answer (score 1):

The basic format of the `ssh` command is

```
ssh user@server.name
```

`server.name` can be the actual server's name (eg `mymachine.local`) or the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear to me if you are trying to connect TO or FROM the AIX machine.  If you are trying to connect TO it, you will need SSH software.  Most Linux distros come with "ssh" do do this.  If you are using Windows, [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is well regarded.